# Prove that the eigenvalue with largest absolute value is positive and real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius, positive-matrices

> Let $A \in \mathbb R_{>0}^{n \times n}$. Consider all the eigenvalues of $A$, including complex-valued ones. Prove that the eigenvalue that has the largest absolute value is a positive real eigenvalue.

I also expect the proof using just elementary linear algebra.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron_root_is_strictly_maximal_eigenvalue_for_positive_(and_primitive)_matrices

Comment: Is [Gelfand's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula) elementary for You?

Comment: @PeterMelech I suspect not, since this seems to be in the context of a second course of linear algebra, which would not cover operatory theory.

Comment: Actually one just needs $\rho(A^m-\varepsilon I)\leq\rho(A^m)\leq\rho(A)^m\leq 1$ that can be proven in an elementary way and follow the proof in the wiki-article quoted  by Lord Shark

Comment: But then $\rho(A^m-\varepsilon I)\leq\rho(A^m)$ really needs the full Gelfand formula and the positivity of $T=A^m-\varepsilon I$ is crucial. It seems an elementary proof can't be achieved in this way.

Comment: @PeterMelech I have seen a solutions to this problem it used only the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and using contradictions to rule. But the reasoning is very complicated so I would like to find another simpler proof.